# How to make kind of two titles in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, title

i have for example page title:
"Buy Call of duty 3 Game"
I want to show in search results,sidebars and anywhere in the website only "Call of duty 3" without all the other words.
but the page must have this title and header name.
how can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

You will want a primary title that is used when viewing the single post or page and for SEO. Then if you want a shorter title to be used elsewhere, you'll need to create a post metadata field, which is a [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

### Creating a Custom Field

Creating custom fields is relatively easy as they are built into the WordPress back-end by default.

- For a post or page, click on the "Screen Options" tab at the right top right.
- Make sure the "Custom Fields" checkbox is checked.

[image]

- Then scroll down to the Custom Fields meta box.
- Enter the name, such as `shorter_title`
- Enter the short title for this post or page.

[image]
 - Click on the Update or Publish to save/create the post.

WordPress takes care of saving or updating the post's metadata for this custom field.  Its meta key is `shorter_title` or whatever "Name" you gave it.  That's how it's stored in the `wp_postmeta` database table and how you will access it for use.

[image]

### How to Display It

WordPress gives you constructs to access the post metadata (i.e. custom field).  You will use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) in the areas where you want to display this shorter title vs. the post title.

Instead of doing `the_title()` or `get_the_title()`, you'll do the following:

```
$shorter_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shorter_title', true );
```

Now to render that out to the browser, you'd do the following, assuming you are using an `<h2>` and the class I'm showing:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php esc_html_e( $shorter_title ); ?></h2>
```

Notice that the code is escaping the value from the variable to keep the web page safe for your viewers.

### Designing a Better Meta Box

Yes, you can design a better meta box instead of the built-in Custom Field one that WordPress supplies.  You can do that yourself or use something like CMB2.

In this case, as you only have one metadata, I'd recommend building it yourself to avoid adding a third party plugin and dependency.

Comment: Nice. For added ease of use you could wrap that in an output function similar to `the_title()` - `if (!function_exists('the_shorter_title')) {
 function the_shorter_title() {
  $shorter_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'shorter_title', false );
  esc_html_e( $shorter_title );
 }
}` Usage: `the_shorter_title()`;

Comment: I'm using custom theme and i'm getting array return.

Comment: @warez Sorry, `get_post_meta()` needs the 3rd parameter to be a `true` value in order to get back a "single" and not array.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have another question if it's ok.
How can i make the search will search for the short title and not the original?